# reload (update) a module file in the interpreter

Tags: python, module

Let's say I have this python script `script.py` and I load it in the interpreter by typing

```
import script
```

and then I execute my function by typing:

```
script.testFunction(testArgument)
```

OK so far so good, but when I change `script.py`, if I try to import again the script doesn't update. I have to exit from the interpreter, restart the interpreter, and then import the new version of the script for it to work.

What should I do instead?

Comment: **Question**: hhhhmmm, how would I reload this module named 'script'? **Answer**: `reload(script)`. +1 for Python!

Comment: BTW I love somebody edited my original question !!! LoL!!

Answer (score 11):

You can issue a `reload script`, but that will not update your existing objects and will not go deep inside other modules.

**Fortunately this is solved by `IPython` - a better python shell which supports auto-reloading.**

To use autoreloading in `IPython`, you'll have to type `import ipy_autoreload` first, or put it permanently in your `~/.ipython/ipy_user_conf.py`.

Then run:

> ```
> %autoreload 1
> %aimport script
> ```

`%autoreload 1` means that every module loaded with `%aimport` will be reloaded before executing code from the prompt. This will *not* update any existing objects, however.

See http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html for more fun things you can do.

Comment: You can also do ```%load_ext autoreload``` http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html

Answer (score 7):

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload

> #### reload(module)
>
> Reload a previously imported module. The argument must
>   be a module object, so it must have been successfully imported before.
>   This is useful if you have edited the module source file using an
>   external editor and want to try out the new version without leaving
>   the Python interpreter. The return value is the module object (the
>   same as the module argument).

Comment: Aye, it does need a sarcasm font. My thanks were sincere.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution that has helped me greatly is to maintain a copy of `sys.modules` keys and pop the new modules after the import to force re-imports of deep imports:

```
>>> oldmods = set(sys.modules.keys())
>>> import script
>>> # Do stuff
>>> for mod in set(sys.modules.keys()).difference(oldmods): sys.modules.pop(mod)
>>> import script
```