# Python REPL just like in Clojure

Tags: python-3.x, clojure, pycharm, read-eval-print-loop, cider

How can I access Python REPL just like in Clojure Emacs' plugin Cider? I am interested in interacting with the working program. Or even hot reload. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think unfortunately the answer is “possible but not recommended”: [hot reloading / swapping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862871/hot-reloading-swapping-with-python)

Python just wasn’t designed for this sort of thing the way that Clojure was. Getting a remote shell, might be possible, but not reloading files and updating the shell as you go.