# How to restart python code from any desired point in the code after making a change during debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, ide

I'm debugging a python code in visual studio code. I have employed breakpoints. I got an error and corrected it. How can I restart from that error point? (I mean, how can I avoid re-running everything from the beginning.) Also, let me know if there is a way in any other IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This is called hot reloading, but it comes with a cost

this seems to be your best bet, https://github.com/breuleux/jurigged

also this is a duplicate of [hot reloading / swapping with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862871/hot-reloading-swapping-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in the launch.json file:

```
  "autoReload": {
    "enable": true
  },
```

You can refer to [this page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-may-2021-release/#new-debugger-feature-live-reload-for-python-scripts) for more information.